# Is there any better implementation for this switch case construct?

Tags: c, embedded

I'm working on an embedded system where a register hast to be accessed and after that to be incremented to achieve the result I'm looking for, since the machine is notifying and configured to react on my access and changing or not changing the flag. So the `switch`'s argument has to be kept as it is, since it would otherwise change the behaving of the embedded system.

But there may occur a situation where I don't want to get any of the cases get invoked. But I still need to acces and increment the argument of the `switch`.

(More indepth I'm converting a sequence of analog values to digital values conversions step by step. The index is used to stay synchronized with the current conversion and relating it with the corresponding case to handle the figure correct. There may occur a state in which the index desynchronisizes to the current conversion so the sequence of conversions must be run through without any of the cases getting invoked (to prevent setting wrong data) untill the sequence is finished and the resynchroinisation can get performed)

The way I'm currently doing this is this:

```
switch (RunIndex++)/*RunIndex may only be accessed one time per execution
of this construct and has to be incremented in the same step. thats given.*/
{
   if (RunIndexSyncedWithADCensured == false)
   {
     break;
   }
   case 0:
     Case0RelatedData = SomeOperationsForCase0(RawData);
     break;
   case 1:
     Case1RelatedData = SomeOperationsForCase1(RawData);
     break;
   case 2:
     Case2RelatedData = SomeOperationsForCase2(RawData);
     break;
   default:
     RunIndex = 0;
     break;
}
```

This construct does the job but it looks like it is a bit controversial and I don't feel well by considering about committing this into productinal code.

So is there a better looking way to achieve the same, without the need of additional variables or assignements?

**note:**

Also it may be relevant, that this is in the first part of a interupt function consisting of 2 parts.
The first part handles what has to happen `if()` a conversion is finished. The second part, what has additional to be done `if()` this conversion also ended the sequence. So it is no option to simply return from the function without getting into the second part. and there is currently no loop structure where an `if(...)break;` may break out. (What is also the reason why I'm putting the if inside the switch scope, as it is at least by standard a valid way to break out.)

Comment: why you include `if` block inside `switch`?

Comment: @venki to prevent, as I said in the OP, the cases getting invoked in case the state is present in which the sync isnt ensured.

Comment: Did you know the `if` block never executes?

Comment: This code makes no sense to me.

Comment: I noticed it after Santosh pointed me on... I'm fixing the snippet, 1 moment.

Comment: Since there is no benefit of this in any way (since it isn't even working as expected... don't know how I came across the idea it could) I decided to capsulate now each case with that if. What will blow up the code but At least won't create any confusion+ do ing the job aswell.

Comment: Do not compare with `bool` constants! That is hard to read. Instead use the value directly as condition (here, you have to negate): `if ( !RunIndexSyncedWithADCensured )`

Comment: @Olaf: whats wrong with it given the stdbool.h is included?

Comment: I did not write not to use `bool`! Read my proposed version out loud (reading the `!` as "not").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the `if()` inside `switch()` will never be executed.
Consider the below code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 2;

    switch(i) {
        if (i == 2) {
            printf("I M HERE\n");
        }
        case 1:
            printf("1\n");
        break;
        case 2:
            printf("2\n");
        break;
        default:
            printf("default\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For your code: you expect the string **`I M HERE`** to be printed. But that is not the case. 
The output for the above code snippet is:

```
2
```

**`No statements before case/default(switch constructs): is executed inside switch`**

Now to answer for

> I don't want to get any of the cases get invoked. But I still need to acces and increment the argument of the switch

Just move the `if()` outside to the switch().

```
if (RunIndexSyncedWithADCensured) {
    switch (RunIndex++) {
        case 0:
            Case0RelatedData = SomeOperationsForCase0(RawData);
            break;
            /* Other cases here */
        default:
           RunIndex = 0;
           break;
    }
} else
    RunIndex++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not save the value first and then increment it and use the saved value in the switch? By the way this also includes two accesses, first to read the value from RunIndex and the second to increment it.

```
int runIndex = (RunIndex++);
if (RunIndexSyncedWithADCensured )
{
    switch (runIndex)/*RunIndex may only be accessed one time per execution
    of this construct and has to be incremented in the same step. thats given.*/
    {
        case 0:
            Case0RelatedData = SomeOperationsForCase0(RawData);
            break;
        case 1:
            Case1RelatedData = SomeOperationsForCase1(RawData);
            break;
        case 2:
           Case2RelatedData = SomeOperationsForCase2(RawData);
           break;
        default:
           RunIndex = 0;
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first statement, it first reads and stores the value of RunIndex in runIndex, and then it increments. So you do not need to -1. I don't see any problems in terms of efficiency in any of the code snippets here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using adjacent index numbers, you could make an array of function pointers to replace the switch. That's what the optimizer will turn the switch into anyhow. So instead of your obscure switch, you get this:

```
if (RunIndexSyncedWithADCensured)
{
  SomeOperationsForCase[RunIndex](RawData);
}

RunIndex++;
if (RunIndex > MAX)
{
  RunIndex = 0;
}
```

---

Completely unrelated to the switch statement design: in case `RunIndex` is a sensitive volatile variable such as some hardware register, then you shouldn't use it directly in any form of computations. Make a copy of it:

```
volatile int RunIndex; 
...

int index = RunIndex; // read from RunIndex

if (RunIndexSyncedWithADCensured)
{
  SomeOperationsForCase[index](RawData);
}

index++;
if (index > MAX)
{
  index  = 0;
}

RunIndex = index; // write to RunIndex
```

This is standard practice for all such volatile variables.

Comment: But in this code you are reading multiple times from RunIndex and are working with it, aren't you? It looks prety readable, thats nice. But I guess thoose function calls would decrease the performance isntead of the switch case variant, wouldn't they?

Comment: @Zaibis This code is equivalent to your original code, save for the if statement fix. As I said, the optimizer will likely turn your switch into something like the above, especially if the switch is large.

Comment: @Zaibis As usual when performance comes up, it is useless to discuss it without a very specific system in mind. You should write readable code, period. If you do consider performance, you have to consider how much time the integer comparisons take in relation to how much time a function call takes, and then you also have to consider how much the code above improved branch prediction. Also, the compiler might be able to do inlining somehow, although they usually aren't when it comes to function pointers.

Comment: I absolutley aggree about readable code and the inlining/function pointer stuff. But I don't aggre that the code is the same. In your snippet I see RunIndex's value getting accessed/read at least 2 times if there is no sync and 3 times when it is synced. this would be fatal for my system since the controller is going to start the next conversion as soon as the RunIndex is read. So your code would just discard and desync a lot of conversions. (Remember I'm talking about an embedded system, not about an OS application)

Comment: @Zaibis You should have made it clear it is a volatile variable then. You'd have to read it into a temporary variable. Anyway, that's another issue entirely: how to properly use hardware registers in embedded systems. I'll update with an example.